# Get 3 lowest values from an array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I know that `min()` can get me the lowest value from an array, however I need the 3 lowest values from an array.

assuming my array is named `$myArray`:

I used `asort($myArray)` on my array, then `print_r($myArray)` outputs this:

```
Array (
    [137] => 4.90416668118
    [135] => 7.1203544474
    [18] => 7.2476262434
    [81] => 8.37903400152
    [33] => 9.1074567001
    [4] => 9.90788482793
    [138] => 10.2493339987
    [5] => 11.6024401676
    [63]...and so on until
    [124] => 8727.73285117
    [153] => 8727.73285117
    [117] => 8727.73285117
)
```

How can I get the 3 first values or the X first values should I need to...

**I SHOULD HAVE SPECIFIED**:  Is it possible to do this with losing the keys?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
asort($yourarray, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r(array_slice($yourarray, 0, 3, true));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Anyway to do it without losing the keys?  Will most likely tag this as answer array_slice is very useful and I can probably get what I need now...

Comment: Yes, just set the last parameter to `true`, to preserve the keys.

Comment: Gold! Thanks. Will accept as soon as it lets me...it's right there in the docs isn't it....

Answer (score 2):

Like Brad's answer, but use `ksort` to preserve the keys in your associated array:

```
ksort( $arr );
print_r( array_slice( $arr, 0, 3, true ) );
```

Comment: `asort()` maintains the key association, does it not?  I thought `ksort()` did its sorting by key, which is not what is needed here.  He wants sorting by value.